# xCode Navigation Controller - How to assign another view as the root view

Tags: xcode

I want to implement a navigation bar. When I add the nav bar controller it adds a table view. But I don't want a table view! Is there a way to reset that relationship to a different view type?

Answer (score 0):

May be adding it as a subview could be a solution?